# Setting up multiple projects with EF core in separate project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

How should I setup a solutions with multiple projects, one project is ASP Web API (set as startup project) and the other API.Data project (just standard class library).

I have the following error after running `Add-Migration`:

> Startup project 'API.Data' targets framework '.NETStandard'. There is
>   no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it
>   cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework Core Package
>   Manager Console Tools with this project, add an executable project
>   targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core that references this project,
>   and set it as the startup project; or, update this project to
>   cross-target .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Should I install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in the API.Data project or the main startup project with all the assemblies?

I installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` for the API.Data project, the main API project is set as the startup project.

I get this error:

> Your startup project 'API' doesn't reference
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the
>   Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is
>   correct, install the package, and try again.

If I change the startup project to the API.Data project I get this error:

> Startup project 'API.Data' targets framework '.NETStandard'.
>   There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects
>   targeting it cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework
>   Core Package Manager Console Tools with this project, add an
>   executable project targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core that
>   references this project, and set it as the startup project; or, update
>   this project to cross-target .NET Framework or .NET Core.

When I build solution I these build warnings for all the assemblies:

```
 Consider app.config remapping of assembly ...
```

csproj file:

https://pastebin.com/fG7w81a8

Comment: You could add your project files to check the dependencies

Comment: Also, did you installed 'dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design'?

Comment: Your csproj file could help to determine a problem

Comment: @rekiem87 https://pastebin.com/fG7w81a8

Answer (score 14):

In `Entity Framework Core 2.2+`

In your library project containing the `DBContext` (let's call it `MyProject.Data`), make sure you have these packages installed (your versions will probably be different, also you may need to change `SqlServer` to whatever you're using for your DB):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
```

In my `Startup.cs` I also specified the `Migration Assembly` but I do not think this is necessary:

```
        services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                serverOptions => serverOptions.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyDataContext).Assembly.FullName));
```

Then in the `Package Manager Console`, change the directory to your Service/Startup project, for example:

```
cd .\src\MyProject.Service
```

Then depending on what you want to do, still in the `Package Manager Console`:

**Add Migration**:

```
dotnet ef migrations add MyMigrationName --startup-project ./ --project ../MyProject.Data/
```

**Update Database**:

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project ./ --project ../MyProject.Data/
```

**Generate Script (last Migration)**:

```
dotnet ef migrations script --startup-project ./ --project ../MyProject.Data/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using net core 2.1, you need to install the [Command Line Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet), then check if you can do `dotnet ef`.

If you have your entities in other project, you still need to add as reference to the main project, then, `run dotnet ef migrations add`, from the main project, the one where you have your connection strings defined, you can add -v to run in verbose mode, that way you can catch more errors.

For example, we have our project *vtae.data*, this project have a folder called *context*, where we have two context, `core` and `stats`, then, we have out *vtae.api* project, this is an ASPNET Core app, with an `appsettings.json` file, which contains our connection strings and imports the *vtae.data* project, so, to work with EF, we just get into the folder of the *vtae.api* project and then there we run our commands, like

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context CoreContext -v
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here and this is how you solve it:

> Run this command on CLI with the option --startup-project=[Path_to_Your_Executable_Project]

This happens because you are probably trying to run this command in a classlib project which is separated from the main executable project.

Answer (score 0):

In net5.0,

I had the same problem and the only thing that I did just adjust Startup.cs with this code:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
    x => x.MigrationsAssembly("API.Data")));
```

Then rebuilding the project and excuting `Add-Migration NewMigration`.